# Unable to POST, HttpURLConnection defaults to GET

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to POST to a certain endpoint, when the GET method isn't allowed for that URL. When using HTTPURLConnection, I set both the request method to be post and doOutput to be true.

However for some reason, when I put a breakpoint on the InputStream (where it fails due to a missing file), the request method is GET, and doOutput is false (with only doInput being true). This leads to a 404, <del>method not allowed</del> **not found**, saying no matching handler for method [get]. Why is it ignoring my settings and going on as if I entered nothing?

```
String result = null;
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(baseUrl  + getTokenPath).openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((clientid + ":" + secret).getBytes()));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);


        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());

        wr.writeBytes ("grant_type=client_credentials");
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        result = response.toString();
        rd.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is not "method not allowed" it is "Not found", was that a typo or you are seeing the wrong error?

Comment: I meant 404, not found, that was a typo.

Comment: when you receive 404 it means exactly that. The page you are requesting is not present at the endPoint. So double check the address you are sending your post. If the problem was the method you would receive another error code instead of a 404.

Comment: I already know that, I said earlier that when I set a breakpoint before I get the input stream, the HttpURLConnection is still GET with doOutput as false. It ignores the values I insert and continues with the default values.

Comment: Can you show the code in the endPoint that is supposed to receive this post?

Comment: I am not the owner of this endpoint, I am only having problems with the HttpUrlConnection class, the endpoint works properly.

Comment: @SmashedBug Read about [RestTemplate](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/) It's better to use than `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not close `DataOutputStream` until You read all data from `InputStream`.

```
wr.close ();
```

Closing stream causes You dropping the connection. Flush is enough to send `POST` request.

```
wr.flush ();
```